# What is the portion of an integral solution after the comma?

Tags: integration, real-numbers

I'm trying to brush up on my Calculus (took it 15 years ago) just for a little fun.  I solved the following integral, given as a sample "easy" integral by a buddy who is still up to snuff on Calc:

$$\int 3x^2 \sin(x^3+1) \, dx$$

I remembered to do substitution, looked up the integral of sin, and came to the correct answer:

$$-cos(x^3+1) + C, \, x \, \in \mathbb{R}$$

The part after the comma I just wrote down as muscle memory:  $$x \, \in \mathbb{R}$$

What is the purpose of that piece of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply states that $x$ can be any real number for your problem.

Note that this isnt always the case! For example :

$\int \frac{1}{x^2} dx = -\frac{1}{x} + C, x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x\ne0$.

Comment: To be more specific (or pedantic), is it correct to say "the portion of the solution following the comma states the values of x which are valid for the problem?"

Comment: Yes, your idea is right. Please allow me to correct your English though : "The portion of the solution following the comma signifies the values of $x$ for which the solution is valid."

Comment: Dang!  I started with the word "solution" instead of problem.  Then second-guessed myself.  I guess I'll never learn that lesson.  THANK YOU for the edit.  Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It reminds you that, for any given constant $C$ (real number), one has
$$ \left( -\cos(x^3+1) + C \right)^\prime = 3x^2 \sin(x^3+1) $$
*for all real numbers* $x$. There are no domain restrictions.